how can i use libharu convert chinese text to pdf
bool textConvertToPDF(std::vector\<std::string\> text, std::string filePath)

{

HPDF_Doc pdf = HPDF_New(nullptr, nullptr);

if (!pdf) {

//throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create PDF document");

return true;

}

std::vector\<std::string\> lines = text;

//lines.push_back(text);

try {

// 添加一个页面

HPDF_Page page = HPDF_AddPage(pdf);

HPDF_UseCNSFonts(pdf);

HPDF_UseCNSEncodings(pdf);

HPDF_SetCompressionMode (pdf, HPDF_COMP_ALL);

// 设置页面尺寸（A4）

HPDF_Page_SetSize(page, HPDF_PAGE_SIZE_A4, HPDF_PAGE_PORTRAIT);

HPDF_SetCurrentEncoder(pdf, "UTF-8");

HPDF_Font font = HPDF_GetFont(pdf, HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile(pdf, "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.meitu.MTIKDemo/files/simsun.ttf", HPDF_TRUE), "UTF-8");

HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize(page, font, 12);

// 设置起始位置

float x = 50; // 左边距

float y = HPDF_Page_GetHeight(page) - 50; // 顶部边距

float line_height = 14; // 每行文本的高度（包含行间距）

// 绘制每一行文本

HPDF_Page_BeginText(page);

for (const auto& line : lines) {

HPDF_Page_TextOut(page, x, y, line.c_str());

y -= line_height; // 移动到下一行

if (y \< 50) { // 如果超出页面底部，创建新页面

HPDF_Page_EndText(page);

page = HPDF_AddPage(pdf);

HPDF_Page_SetSize(page, HPDF_PAGE_SIZE_A4, HPDF_PAGE_PORTRAIT);

HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize(page, font, 12);

y = HPDF_Page_GetHeight(page) - 50;

HPDF_Page_BeginText(page);*your text*

}

}

HPDF_Page_EndText(page);

// 保存 PDF 文件

HPDF_SaveToFile(pdf, filePath.c_str());

} catch (...) {

HPDF_Free(pdf);

//throw;

return false;

}

HPDF_Free(pdf);

return true;

}


remove  the extra mention of UTF 8  can not be work

HPDF_Page_SetSize(page, HPDF_PAGE_SIZE_A4, HPDF_PAGE_PORTRAIT);
HPDF_SetCurrentEncoder(pdf, "UTF-8");
char* fontName = HPDF_LoadTTFontFromFile(pdf, "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.meitu.MTIKDemo/files/simsun.ttf", HPDF_TRUE);
HPDF_Font font = HPDF_GetFont(pdf, fontName, "UTF-8");
HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize(page, font, 12);
like this? But this is the same, it doesn't work
